# String with regex comparison in python fails in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to compare string with regex in python as follows,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re

str1 = "Expecting property name: line \d+ column \d+ (char \d+)"
str2 = "Expecting property name: line 3 column 2 (char 44)"

print(re.search(str1,str2))

if re.search(str1,str2) :
    print("Strings are same")
else :
    print("Strings are different")
```

I always get following output

> None
>   Strings are different

I am not able to understand what is wrong here.
Can someone suggest/point me what is wrong with this ?

Comment: The *brackets* are *interpreted*.

Comment: `str1 = r"Expecting property name: line \d+ column \d+ \(char \d+\)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *escape* the brackets, since otherwise these are seen as "grouping directives" by the regex engine:

```py
str1 = r"Expecting property name: line \d+ column \d+ \(char \d+\)"
#                                                     ^         ^
```

Note that search does *not* mean a *full* match: it simply means a substring of `str2` needs to match. So you might want to add `^` and `$` *anchors*.

Comment: Thank you for reply Willem, so final regex string should be `r"^Expecting property name: line \d+ column \d+ \(char \d+\)$"` right ?

Comment: @AnkurTank: given you want an exact match, yes, but if `'foobar Expecting property name: line 123 column 123 \(char 123) qux other nonsense'` is acceptable, then of course you can omit the anchors. It depends on *what* you want.

Comment: Got it.Thanks for help.